# IE 11 redirect to new link is not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, redirect, browser, tcp

we have a captive portal application. In which the user is authenticated, before accessing the internet.
After authentication, the browser automatically redirects to user requested URL.

But after authentication, the page is not redirecting to requested URL.
This occurs only for IE11, all other browsers the redirection works fine.

By inspecting the TCP dump, only IE11 use old TCP connection for redirection and for all other browser, new TCP connection is used for redirection.

redirection will occur after few seconds (after success auth) using

```
window.location = "redirect-url";
```

The IE11 keeps spinning with status "Waiting for ..." & finally displays 'page not found'.

please guide to resolve this issue